# JavaFX CSS image loading on Linux

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I would like to load an image as a background image in a css file included by my fxml file.

I am certain that the CSS is working, because I can change the background color for instance, but when I try :

```css
GridPane{
    -fx-background-image: url('wallpaper.jpg');
}
```

I always end up with this warning :

```
WARNING: Error loading image: file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/btnv2/ws_client/out/production/ws_client/wallpaper.jpg
```

Now the weird thing is that the image path displayed by the error is correct, and when my friend pulled the project the image displayed correctly for him with no error.

I am running Arch Linux and he's on MacOs, i figured that might have something to do with it.

This is the production project structure :

[image: Structure]

Comment: As an experiment, try temporarily replacing the real wallpaper.jpg with some other image (renamed to wallpaper.jpg of course), to determine whether the image itself might be the cause.

Comment: I just tried doing that, no luck

Comment: Try reading the image in your code with [ImageIO.read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)):  `ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("wallpaper.jpg"));`  If it fails, you will get an informative exception on the reason for the failure.

Comment: @VGR Your snipped threw no error, so I ended up setting the background image in code which made it work for both of us. Still no idea why the CSS wouldn't load the image.Do I leave the question open to try and find a CSS solution or do I have to close it ?

Comment: I think it is a valid question.  You may want to mention which version of JavaFX you are using, and which version your friend used.